# How will be the effect of temperature and density on a sound wave at the same medium?

Tags: acoustics

Let think about a sound wave travelling a medium.There is a theory that if the temperature is  increased,the speed of sound wave will be also increased as the molecules have more energy and it can viberate more so the sound wave can travel faster.I would like to complain that  if we rise the temperature  of the medium,the molecules become less condensed and the speed of sound will be decreased.Then,how can we say that speed of sound is directly proportional to the temperature?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound, roughly proportional to the square root of the temperature $v_{sound} \propto \sqrt T$ and and since $T \propto rms[v_{molecule}]$ you get $v_{sound}  \propto rms[v_{molecule}]$